# How colonialism have been done right (benevolently)?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, europe, british-empire, colonial-america

The British Empire (& Europeans, Arabs etc.) colonised many countries but the colonial experience, advertised as a "westernizing the backward people for their own good" masked the oppression, bloodshed, racism & exploitation of people & resources on a large scale.

But I wonder how differently would things/events need to be carried out where the intent & outcomes of "colonialism" would have been positive from start to finish for all countries involved?

Comment: Hi. This question isn't really about history , "What if" type questions are off topic here.  But I will say that there is no way whatsoever that colonialism could've been "done right". It didn't happen because of the curiosity of rugged,  adventurous individuals. ***It happened because there was money to be made***. And when there are fortunes to be made, ethics go out the window.

Answer (score 3):

This question kind of reminds me of how decades ago I used to read my papers' weekly [Miss Manners column](https://www.missmanners.com/). It seemed like once a month or so someone would write in asking "What is the polite way to *X*", where *X* is something inherently rude.

She usually had an impressively gentle way of informing them that the only polite path is to not *X* at all. Meanwhile I'm mentally calling them all kinds of nasty names, which I suppose is why [she's Miss Manners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judith_Martin), and I'm not. But dammit people, you gotta learn that some things are just inherently *wrong*, and **there's no "right way" to do something wrong**. You can't just big brain your way around morals.

The reason this reminds me of that of course, is that *colonialism*, as normally defined, cannot happen without taking someone else's stuff. Their land, their resources, their freedom, their lives sometimes. You've gotta take at least some of that, or its not colonialism.

There is no "benevolent" way to take someone's stuff from them. It can't be done.

Comment: The decision making around https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinelese is not an answer but probably a useful data point.

Comment: @GremlinWranger - Yup. The only way to win the game is not to play.

Comment: I don’t even think the way described in the famous SF story "[Monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_(novel))" would work.

Comment: Well, from a utilitarian POW colonialism could be positive. Imagine a small elite that oppresses a big majority - and then a colonial power ousts that elite and give the majority more freedom than before. I am sure this has happened.

Comment: @T.E.D. Your definition of colonialism is far from the reality of 19th century European colonialism. This colonialism did not take land (people remained there with their activities, did not take freedom -in face they often got more-, took lives on specific situations, not systematically.

Comment: @totalMongot you may need to be more precise than '19th century'. Plenty of creative land acquisition, slavery and genocide in there across the pacific, and the Belgian Congo was the result of lessons of that era.

Comment: @GremlinWranger You're right, so I was thinking about British or French colonies in Africa. I don't know well about the Pacific colonisation, was it destructive?

Comment: Without disagreeing with the main point, I would say some of the USA colonial enterprises (Philippines and China) were quite mild by the standards of the era. Of course, usually the USA has prefered indirect domination through meddling with local governments (as in Latin America).

Comment: @totalMongot useful search terms to start with are blackbirding, Liliʻuokalani of Hawaii, Treaty of Waitangi (esp the differences between versions, a problem even if both parties have good faith), the Moriori, Easter island and stolen generation. Less familiar with the history of Philippines but at least two major rebellions there in the period that I'm assuming did not come from nothing.